# Is there ever a reason not to fuse your equipment?

Tags: tales-of-zestiria

I've been finding a lot of equipment that are not as good as what I'm currently using. Gald also doesn't seem to be an issue.

Is there ever a reason not to go ahead and fuse the equipment together to upgrade the equipment's stats?

Comment: I found that gald does become as issue after a little while. I also personally found myself using aging equipment for use in fusing when I should have been upgrading. But that is obviously more a mindset rather an real reason.

Comment: @Reafexus So you're saying that it's more important to upgrade to new, better equipment first before I start to fuse old equipment?

Comment: It's a Tales game so you can't really go wrong with any way of doing things. I preferred to just buy my upgrades after a while. That said I didn't really understand the whole 5x10 grid skill system so I imagine you can fuse much more smartly to maximize output. and surpass purchases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fusing equipment increases your equipment's stats. This is good. You want the highest +X values for your equipment that you can find.

But Fusing equipment means potentially changing skills. This may be good or bad. The logic there is simple -- each item has 4 "slots" which can each contain a skill. When an object is fused, the slots are combined -- 1 to 1, 2 to 2, etc. If the skill is the same in both slots, it remains. If the skills are different, they will become a locked 3rd skill (this will be shown on the Fusion screen).

Having duplicates (stacks), adjacent (horizontal), or an entire column (vertical) skills give you E-Bonus meta skills. Some of these skills are pretty good, such as the 1st column bonus, Soljurr, which gives a flat bonus to *all* stats.

Essentially, the E-Bonuses you're getting might be more valuable than the raw stats you're gaining from a +X fused equipment.

The other reason to not fuse is much simpler -- fused items can be resold for much less money than unfused items. So if you're trying to make money, don't use Lailah or Edna's Fusion ability -- the base equipment is better value.

Comment: Is fused equipment explicitly less valuable (+0 = 100g while +1 = 50g) or is it just that you now have 2 instead of 1?

Comment: @Reafexus The formula isn't that simple (and/or I haven't cared to see if it is), but it is *explicitly* less valuable.